# Comando auto_increment para Id não funciona após apagar dados e reescrevê-los

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Quando crio uma tabela com a coluna "Id int not null auto_increment" e insiro valores na tabela, após deletar os valores e reinseri-los, o Id não parte do 1, e as vezes com uma ordem aleatória. E além de aparecer 8 row(s) affected Records, aparece também 8 Duplicates, mesmo os valores já terem sido deletados da tabela. Alguém poderia me ajudar a restaurar meu Id do 1 após reiniciar a tabela?

[image: Script:]

Comment: Entendi que posso dar: alter table games  auto_increment=1, mas como posso fazer isso caso delete um id no meio dos outros para organizá-los novamente?

Comment: O `id` nunca se reorganiza, se você quiser limpar a tabela totalmente, inclusive o `auto_increment`, utilize o comando `TRUNCATE TABLE nome_da_sua_tabela;`. Lembre-se que esse comando limpa todos os dados da tabela.

Comment: Evite postar imagens do código. Dê preferência para postar o código em si, dessa forma o pessoa poderá testar e encontrar a melhor solução. [mcve]

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.